# Создаю телеграм бота на Thonny и он выдает мне ошибку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал код в компьютерной академии и отправил себе через мэйл
скачал приложения
написал код
Бот в телеграме высвечивается но никак не реагирует на мои сообщения что делать

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score -1):

Есть несколько вариантов решения.

1. Измени название папки с `telebot` на что то другое
2. pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Если ответ помог, поставь галочку возле моего ответа